# How to access elasticsearch from Linux Guest (Virtualbox) to OSX Host?

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

As the question states, if I have a linux/centos VM in virtualbox, how do I go to:

10.0.0.1:9200 to access elasticsearch?

On the guest, I am getting a "Connection timed out error".
From my OSX host, I can see elasticsearch is running with "localhost:9200". I can tell Apache is accessible from the Linux guest because 10.0.0.1 shows the apache webpage fine. In my OSX configuration, I have "Web Sharing" enabled, which is why I assume that the guest is able to access port 80, but what about elasticsearch?

I tried:

1. sudo ipfw add 7000 allow tcp from any to any dat-port 9200

Logged out, the logged back in. Still getting a "The connection has timed out" in guest CentOS VM.

1. Drag the /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch into the 
   "System Preferences" -> "Security" -> "Firewall"

Still getting a "The connection has timed out" in CentOS VM.

This feel like it should be something very simple.... note that elasticsearch was installed with homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the port 9200 open somewhere along the line. If your OSX Host is on the same network as your linux guest, then it is probably the firewall. You can change firewall settings on the OSX host by going to `System Preferences > Security > Firewall`.

If there is networking equipment between the computers (Based on the IP address I do not believe there is) you also need to open the port there as well.

If the port you need to open is not used it a .app application you will need to add it manually using the console. The command to do this is `sudo ipfw add 7000 allow tcp from any to any dat-port 9200`. `7000` is the rule number, and `9200` is the port.

Additionally this is not the correct site for questions like this, the best place would be [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) the stack exchange site for mac questions.

Comment: How to change firewall settings? I am in OSX Mavericks, it looks like all I can add are "Applications" like, SSH.... but I have no idea how to open up ports.

Comment: I tried the sudo ipfw add 7000 allow tcp from any to any dat-port 9200 and it appeared to successfully add entry, but I still could not access http://10.0.0.9:9200. The connection timed out.

Comment: For the ipfw method you do have to actually disable the firewall from in the settings app. they are 2 different firewalls.

Comment: I have just disabled the firewall. Restarted the VM, tried accessing 10.0.0.9:9200, but still does not work. Apache does work however on port 80 still....

Comment: did you run the ipfw command on the same computer as elastic search was running on

Comment: Yes, I ran that command in the OSX host. Not the Virtualbox CentOS guest.

Comment: I have no idea what is happening at this point. perhaps try changing the port of elastic host to something else.